# Snowflake Total Bytes Over Network at any Given Point of Time

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to check on the snowflake account level, how much data been transferred from snowflake in and out at any given point of time. BYTES_SENT_OVER_THE_NETWORK - I tried to research this column from the Query History table but I couldn't get the given point in time instead I am getting start time and end time and how much bytes transferred. Is there any way we can get these details. Happy to share more context if required.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Data_TRANSFER_HISTORY view in account usage which capture this for COPY, REPLICATION and EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/data_transfer_history.html

For each query data transfer, you can use columns INBOUND_DATA_TRANSFER_BYTES and OUTBOUND_DATA_TRANSFER_BYTES

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html

Comment: Thanks, does this data transfer includes SELECT or INSERT SQLs which I try to do from programmatically into and from Snowflake? Also, what is the difference between Data_TRANSFER_HISTORY and QUERY_HISTORY table, please.